# Is it possible to run tests in parallel using forks with one runner class without using outdated cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using TestNG, Cucumber, but if there is no solution for TestNG, then JUnit is OK as well.

I know how to run tests in different forks using cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin. This plugin will generate a bunch of runners for each feature file, and then maven-surefire-plugin will run runners in different forks if configured appropriately.

But cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin github page says I should not use it anymore. So that means I can not generate runners for each feature file and I have only one runner that includes a bunch of feature files.

But then I can not find how to run those feature files in different forks. There is a possibility to run in different threads, but I was interested in forks...

So is it possible, and if yes, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: With testng u will need to have multiple runners to take advantage of parallel execution with forking. Set these two options in the pom.mxml configuration section of firesafe or surefire - <forkCount> and <reuseForks>.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must have found some way to create more than one runners and run it in forks.
But here is what we have used in our project if the question is still relevant.

Cucumber + Junit

```
Plugin : <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucable-plugin</artifactId>
         <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
         In the configuration tag, 
<generatedRunnerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/parallel/runners</generatedRunnerDirectory>

Plugin : <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        <source>${project.build.directory}/parallel/runners</source>

plugin :  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <forkCount>${fork.count}</forkCount>
          <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.